# How can i post credential using jQuery ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting error using the following code snippet

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            username: id,
            password: pass
        }).success(function(content) { alert('ok'); })
        .error(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   alert(XMLHttpRequest.status); alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState); alert(textStatus); })
        .complete(function() { alert('done'); });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what you want to do, what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: what is the error? also... formatting would be nice...

Comment: Can't debug this without the code before it, where to id,pass,url come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              username: id,
              password: pass
            },
            success: function(content) { alert('ok'); },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
            },
            complete: function() {.. };
         });
    })
```

something like that should work.  You don't just put username and pass in the ajax argument, you creata a `data` object and put the parameters in there.  Also, you put your callbacks as arguments in the `ajax` argument.

Comment: i've just try your post, but still failed, with status "0", readyState "0" and textStatus "error"

Comment: you need actual data for the variables, you know.  url has to be a url, id has to be an id, etc....if it is failing, what do you see on the server?

Comment: url, id & pass are variables in javascript, and the server's not mine, i just need to login the system and will get a ticket string, but failed

Comment: you are going to need to figure out where it is failing. Is the request being sent, Is the server responding?

Comment: i've replaced all the variables using the correct data but still got the error. Sorry that i cannot show you the url, id & password, as they are the secure data for me

Comment: leo, note that I changed my javascript slightly to be `$.ajax`.  Also note, that I didn't fill in the functions you had, I just wanted to show you the structure.  Are you getting a javascript error?  Look in your console.

Comment: Actually, i can use XHR.open('POST', url, id, pass) to get the correct data, but the cross domain issue make me to change the solution to jQuery so that it can work under Safari

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
        username: id,
        password: pass
     },
     success: function(content) 
     { 
        alert('ok'); 
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
     {   
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.status); 
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState); 
        alert(textStatus); 
     },
     complete: function() 
     { 
        alert('done'); 
     }
   });
```

});

Comment: Well... I would guess that the data you are sending is incorrect, or that the data you are receiving is bad. I don't think the problem is with the `ajax()` call.